# xcode cant find libraries after moving project

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7

I just moved my complete xcode project from one folder to another and opened it in xcode. Its complaining about not being able to find libraries ?

```
Ld /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.app/PlugIns/MyApplication.xctest/MyApplication normal i386
cd /Users/UserName/Documents/workspace/App/MyApplication
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApplication.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -bundle_loader /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.app/MyApplication -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Intermediates/MyApplication.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApplicationTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.app/PlugIns/MyApplicationTests.xctest/MyApplicationTests

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: file not found: /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-atxtukaqhznqzheippjrdzpbsuvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)